# Solving for a variable using a logarithm with a base not 10?

Tags: logarithms

So I have this expression: $C=Ba^{(t/D)}-k$ and I'm asked to solve for $t$ using a logarithm with base a $log_{a}$. So far, I've gotten ${((C+k)/B)} = a^{(t/D)}$. How do I move forward?

Comment: Note that $\log_a (a^x) = x$. So taking $\log_a$ of both sides will help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_aa=1$$
$$C +k=Ba^{(t/D)}$$
$$\log_a(C +k)=\log_aB +\log_aa^{(t/D)}$$